Spring Boot gRPC Server Initialization Error: Unable to get public no-arg constructor for NettyServerProvider
I want to configure a gRPC server in my Spring Boot application (Java 17), but I am encountering the following error when trying to instantiate the server:
package org.xenwgram.config;

import io.grpc.Grpc;
import io.grpc.InsecureServerCredentials;
import io.grpc.Server;
import io.grpc.ServerCredentials;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.xenwgram.service.Impl.MessageServiceImpl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Configuration
public class GrpcServerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Server grpcServer() {
        try {
            Server server = Grpc.newServerBuilderForPort(6565, InsecureServerCredentials.create())
                    .build();
            server.start();

            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    server.shutdown().awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }));

            return server;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to start gRPC server", e);
        }
    }
} 

I am using the following dependencies in my build.gradle.kts file:
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.9.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.16"
}

group = "org.xenwgram"
version = "v0.0.1"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/65346162/packages/maven")
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")

    implementation("org.xenwgram:xengram-proto:test-1.1")

    // Spring Boot starter web
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.4.0")

    // Lombok for compile-time code generation
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.1.0")

    // gRPC Spring Boot starter
    implementation("net.devh:grpc-server-spring-boot-starter:3.1.0.RELEASE")

    // gRPC dependencies
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.69.0")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.69.0")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.69.0")

    // Google Protocol Buffers
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:4.29.1")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


The error I am encountering:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grpcServer' defined in class path resource [org/xenwgram/config/GrpcServerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.grpc.Server]: Factory method 'grpcServer' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.grpc.ServerProvider: io.grpc.netty.NettyServerProvider Unable to get public no-arg constructor 

What I have tried:

When using the auto-configuration provided by the grpc-server-spring-boot-starter, everything works fine without issues.
When I use a custom server configuration as shown in the code above, I get the error above.

What I would like to understand:

Why am I encountering the ServiceConfigurationError with
NettyServerProvider?
Is there something wrong with how I am
configuring the gRPC server in Spring Boot?
Should I switch to using the auto-configuration provided by Spring Boot starter?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Something is bringing in an older grpc-netty dependency (the error is about io.grpc.netty instead of io.grpc.netty.shaded). Adding implementation("io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.69.0") should fix it. I'd have to spend more time to detail what is happening.
